# Julia FITSio: FITS table with Float64 and ASCIIString

Tags: julia, astronomy

I am new to Julia, I hope my question is not too trivial.
I try to create a FITS binary table that includes various columns of Float64 and one column of ASCIIString. As explained in the [FITSIO.jl documentation](http://julia-fitsio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), the input to the write() function should be "*a dictionary with ASCIIString keys (giving the column names) and Array values (giving data to write to each column)*".

but it seems that a Dictionary cannot hold mixed types, and I get the following error:

```
data=Dict{"col1"=>[1.0,2.0,3.0], "col2"=>[4.0,5.0,6.0],"col3"=>["toto","tata","titi"]}
LoadError: TypeError: Dict: in parameter, expected Type{T}, got Pair{ASCIIString,Array{Float64,1}} while loading In[408], in expression starting on line 1
```

Does anyone knows how to create a FITS table including columns of mixed types, and in particular Float64 and ASCIIString?
It should be possible, since I can read such a table with the same FITSIO.jl library without problem, but the limited examples in the documentation do not illsutrate such a case.

Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that `ASCIIString` is being deprecated in v0.5... so if you're writing any new code, try to avoid this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the braces to parentheses and you'll create the list you intend.

```rb
data=Dict("col1"=>[1.,2.,3.], "col2"=>[4.,5.,6.], "col3"=>["toto","tata","titi"])
```

You are essentially calling the constructor of the `Dict` type using a sequence of pairs.

---

**Extra info:**
Braces are something else entirely. It's for specifying that the dictionary keys and values should be of (or converted to, if possible) a specific type. e.g.

```rb
julia> Dict{String,Array{Float64,1}}("a"=>[1.,2.,3.], "b"=>[4.,5.,6.])
Dict{String,Array{Float64,1}} with 2 entries:
  "b" => [4.0,5.0,6.0]
  "a" => [1.0,2.0,3.0]

julia> Dict{String,Array{Float64,1}}("a"=>[1.,2.,3.], "b"=>['a','b','c'])
Dict{String,Array{Float64,1}} with 2 entries:
  "b" => [97.0,98.0,99.0]
  "a" => [1.0,2.0,3.0]

julia> Dict{String,Array{Float64,1}}("a"=>[1.,2.,3.], "b"=>["a","b","c"])
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Float64
```

Comment: Terrific, I should have been more careful! 
Now I have another problem. If I try to add the String column to the existing Dictionary, it breaks again:
    data=Dict("col1"=>[1.,2.,3.], "col2"=>[4.,5.,6.])
    data["col3"]=["toto","tata","titi"]
complaining about the types... any idea whether it's possible? thank you!

Comment: If you initialise it with the first two pairs only, julia will infer that this dictionary is specifically one that takes String / Array-of-floats pairs (i.e. it infers the type `Dict{String, Array{Float64, 1}}`. Either add the (String=>String) pair at the same time as the floats to make julia infer it is an array of type `Any`, *or* if you can't, then convert it to one (e.g. `data = convert(Dict{String,Array{Any,1}}, data)`) or make the type explicit at initialisation time (e.g. `data = Dict{String, Array{Any,1}}(<sequence of pairs>)`)

Comment: pleasure. while you're at it, take a look at the following functions, I'm sure you'll find them useful for working with dictionaries if you weren't aware of them already: `haskey` `get` `get!` `getkey` `push!` `delete!`